# iOS: Error when creating encryption keys in unit test

Tags: ios, swift, security, encryption

I have the following code which creates a key pair in the secure enclave.

```
let access = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,                                            
                                             kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
                                             .privateKeyUsage,
                                             nil)!

var attributes: [String: Any] = [
    kSecAttrKeyType as String: encryptionType,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: encryptionBits,
    kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: [
       kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true,
       kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: "abc".data(using: .utf8) as Any,
       kSecAttrAccessControl as String: access,
    ],
]

if Device.hasSecureEnclave {
    attributes[kSecAttrTokenID as String] = kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave
}

var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes as CFDictionary, &error)
```

When running in a simulator or on the device it works just fine. But when I run it in a unit test, an error is returned from the `SecKeyCreateRandomKey` call:

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 
"Key generation failed, error -50" UserInfo={NSDescription=Key generation failed, error -50}
```

After trying a few things I found that the problem was the `kSecAttrIsPermanent` key in the `attributes` dictionary. If I remove it, the unit tests run fine.

All the doco I've read indicates it should be ok, but it's failing every time.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have already seen this:
http://www.openradar.me/36809637

I have the exact same issue and there was nothing in the Xcode 9.3 (beta) release notes to suggest it's been fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I started thinking its my trouble. Did you find any way to workaround? Xcode 9.3

Comment: The issue was `kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true`.  A unit test in Xcode won't let you do this.  However you can create a host application so that unit tests have a simulator to perform the `SecAccessControl*` like functions.

You then select the test project from the **TARGETS** on the General tab select _Host Application_.  This will enable unit test to execute in the host application.